# How to position Icon on right side of text

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-native-ios

I tried many ways but unfortunately it still doesn't work please help me out!

I've tried reversing the Text and Icon but still doesn't work

Here is the class

```
export class More extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
      <View style={styles.list}>

        <View style={styles.hairline}>

          <Text style={styles.text}>

          <Text>أضف إعلانك</Text>

            <Icon name="ios-add" size={20}/>

          </Text>
        </View>

        <View style={styles.hairline}>
        <Text style={styles.text}><Icon name="ios-heart" size={20}/>      إعلانات المفضلة</Text>
        </View>

        </View>
      </View>
    );
      }
    }
```

Here is the StyleSheet

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',

    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
list: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    justifyContent: 'flext-start',
  },
  text: {
    padding: 10,
    textAlign: 'right',
    alignSelf: 'stretch',

  },

  icon: {
    flexDirection: 'row',
    alignItems: 'flex-end'
  },

  hairline: {
    borderBottomColor: '#A2A2A2',
    borderBottomWidth: 1,
},
});
```

I want the Icon to show up on the right side of the text not the left side.

Comment: You can't embed another component inside your `Text` tag

Comment: So what should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
const TextWithIcon = ({ text, iconName }) => (
  <View
    style={{
      display: 'flex',
      flexDirection: 'row',
      alignItems: 'center',
      justifyContent: 'center',
    }}
  >
    <View style={{ marginRight: 8 }}>
      <Text>{text}</Text>
    </View>

    <Icon name={iconName} size={20} />
  </View>
);
```

Comment: Ok, So the Icon is on the right side of the text but the Items are in the center and when I try to align them to the right side it all goes messy.